# Generating new random number in python?

Tags: python

So i'm trying to create this really really simple game in python where the person types a number and if it matches the number that the computer generated the user is prompted with a message saying it got the right number and if its wrong a message saying its wrong, now I cant quite figure it out what I did wrong here because when I run this, I try different numbers multiple times and it always displays me the message that I didnt guess the right number, could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here since I have no idea what the problem is?

```
import random

number = random.randint(0,10)
user_number = input()

while user_number != number:
  if user_number == number:
    print("GREAT! You guessed the right number! :)")
  else:
    print("AWW! You guessed the wrong number, try again! :)")
  input()
```

*EDIT* I have a problem, how would I make my script generate a different number everytime the user inputs something, because what I have right now generates a number and that number never changes (btw thanks to Anton vBR for this updates version that I tweaked a bit):

```
import random

number = random.randint(0,10)
user_number = None
valid_num = [str(i) for i in range(0,10)]
random = 2

while random > 1:
while True:
    user_number = input("Enter a number between 1-10: ")
    if user_number in valid_num:
        user_number = int(user_number)
        break
    else:
        print("Not valid!")
if user_number == number:
    print("GREAT! You guessed the right number! :)")
else:
    print("AWW! You guessed the wrong number, try again! :)")
```

Comment: `input()` never returns a number.

Comment: Ignacio has the right answer, but you will also never get to the right answer section because it is in the while loop, which tests for equality already. If they are equal, it will go past the while loop and end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use this snippet, it makes sure that the user answers one of the following "0","1","2","3".."10" or else it keeps asking for valid input.

```
valid_num = [str(i) for i in range(11)]

while True:
    user_number = input("Enter a number between 1-10: ")
    if user_number in valid_num:
        user_number = int(user_number)
        break
    else:
        print("Not valid!")
```

Now to the full code:

```
import random

number = random.randint(0,10)
user_number = None
valid_num = [str(i) for i in range(11)]

while user_number != number:

    # Ask for user input
    while True:
        user_number = input("Enter a number between 1-10: ")
        if user_number in valid_num:
            user_number = int(user_number)
            break
        else:
            print("Not valid!")

    # Check if correct guess
    if user_number == number:
        print("GREAT! You guessed the right number! :)")
    else:
        print("AWW! You guessed the wrong number, try again! :)")
```

Comment: @Myko Glad I could help! The good thing about this is you can type anything and it won't "break".

Answer (score 0):

The last line of your code is `input()`. All this does is take input, not store it anywhere. To store it, you have to assign it to `user_number` like `user_number = input()`. Also, (assuming you are using Python 3) `input()` returns a string, not a number, so it will never be equal. You have to convert it to a number with `user_number = int(input())`

Comment: Also, from your code, the statement "You got it right" will never get printed out because the while loop will run while `user_number != number`

Answer (score 0):

It will never say you are correct because the while loop says that as long as the number you input is different from the random number, it does the if loop. 
Deleting the while loop should be fine. 
If you want to keep it though you cold turn it into a function.

Answer (score 0):

you must devise the execution blocks (if you go within the time must carry an indentation)

besides that your loop becomes infinite because you do not ask the question inside, you must put the input inside and also devise the code to know where it starts and ends the execution blocks